# How update foreign key for several instances in Django formset

Tags: django

I just need to show the list of all `Child` instances without a parent, when a new `Parent` is created, so a user can set a checkbox in front of those he would like to add to this parent
How to deal with this?

I need to let people assign Foreign key to a number of Child instances in django formset. I can't figure out how to do this:

`models.py`:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   pass

class Child(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(to=Parent, null=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class PartFormset(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Child

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner__isnull=True)

MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(parent_model=Parent,
                                      model=Child,
                                      formset=PartFormset,
                                      extra=0,
                                      can_delete=False,
                                      )
```

this one obviously doesn't work because `inlineformset_factory` misses `fields` argument. But of course if I provide the 'owner' as a field, that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

#### ModelChoiceField is the default field of pk or foreignkey field in ModelForm, but then the interesting point is that foreignkey form_field is overrided as InlineForeignKeyField by add_fields() method in BaseInlineFormSet, and HiddenInput is the default widget of InlineForeignKeyField. So the client browser don't show the field. To fix it as below.

```
class PartFormset(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    model = Child

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner__isnull=True)

    # it works as your mind with jumping over the related method of BaseInlineFormSet, 
    # but you need notice the validate and clean stuff
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(forms.BaseInlineFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
```